# How to turn a polygon array to an IndexedTriangelArray in java3d

Tags: java-3d

I have two polygons and want to turn them into a triangle mesh, using java3d.
But whatever I try results in some kind of error. What am I missing?

Here is some code I've tried:

```
final int n = points.length;
final int m = opoints.length;
final GeometryInfo gi = new GeometryInfo(GeometryInfo.POLYGON_ARRAY);
final Point3d[] npoints = Arrays.copyOf(points, n + m);
System.arraycopy(opoints, 0, npoints, n, m);
gi.setCoordinates(npoints);
gi.setStripCounts(new int[] { n, m });

gi.convertToIndexedTriangles();
final IndexedTriangleArray it = (IndexedTriangleArray) gi.getIndexedGeometryArray();

final Point3d[] newPoints = new Point3d[it.getVertexCount()];

it.getCoordinates(0, newPoints);
//      Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
//      at javax.media.j3d.GeometryArrayRetained.getCoordinates(GeometryArrayRetained.java:5425)
//      at javax.media.j3d.GeometryArray.getCoordinates(GeometryArray.java:3699)

final int[] nidxs = new int[it.getValidIndexCount()];
it.getCoordinateIndices(0, nidxs);
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use the debug mode first to know exactly how the GeometryInfo mutates after the call of convertToIndexedTriangles.

As Java 3D 1.6.0 is open source, look at its source code: https://github.com/hharrison/java3d-utils/blob/master/src/classes/share/com/sun/j3d/utils/geometry/GeometryInfo.java#L507
https://github.com/hharrison/java3d-utils/blob/master/src/classes/share/com/sun/j3d/utils/geometry/Triangulator.java#L625

You can call getCoordinateIndices() and getCoordinates() directly on the GeometryInfo object as far as I know.

I cannot guarantee that my suggestion works with an obsolete version of Java 3D.

Comment: Of course, I can (and will, if necessary) turn to angry-paranoid-developer-mode and debug every step. But I was hoping for someone to point me to a working example. It looks like java3d is something like an orphan project and the users are marooned.

Comment: Using the debug mode has nothing to do with paranoia and it's the same for looking at the source code even though it wouldn't be necessary if the API was easier to use, better documented and better designed. Java 3D isn't an orphan project, I spent several weeks in writing a tutorial about it, I initiated its port to JOGL 2 and Harvey still maintains it. We can't provide examples for absolutely all use cases. We don't abandon Java 3D users but SO isn't the best place to ask for help about Java 3D even though I answer to questions about it here daily, rather go to the official JogAmp forum.

Comment: Moreover, keep in mind that Java 3D is a community project, we do our best (on our spare time) and reading things like "the users are marooned" whereas I spend several hours daily to answer questions on StackOverflow, JogAmp forum and on JavaGaming.org since 2006 is quite discouraging. We can't "feed the babies" and I made an effort to give you enough indications to allow you to learn by yourself and go further. What more do you expect? I won't write the whole code for you. It's not difficult to call gi.getCoordinateIndices() and gi.getCoordinates(). I don't want to be harsh, sorry.

Comment: I am responsible for engine support and I can tell you that some communities are very helpful but sometimes, the best way of helping developers doesn't consist in giving them pieces of code that they don't understand but rather in helping them to solve some of their problems so that they can write the code by themselves, it's more pedagogical and it's exactly what I tried to do with you. Java 3D does most of the hard work for you, you just have to be able to use the (sometimes weird and badly designed) API to retrieve the results, you don't have to compute the triangles by yourself.

Comment: Our forum is here: http://forum.jogamp.org/java3d-f3728156.html Our IRC channel is here: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=jogamp and my tutorial is here: http://tinyurl.com/cf47kcb You're not alone.

Comment: Sorry if did I upset you, but all in all what you are saying is: "the code is your friend". And, yes it is, indeed.

Comment: In the meantime, I found (old, but good) tutorials for java3d: http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/courses/ITNP3B/Java3D/Tutorial/ ( I had to trick google to show me the parent directory instead of the single pdf files. It will take me awhile to study this.

Comment: It's open source, it's a chance to understand what you do, it's what I meant, sorry. I gave you the link so that you can dive into the parts involved in your problem and in my humble opinion, this is exactly what you should do instead of looking for an example doing what you want. You can look at j3d-examples on java.net too. As we haven't modified the public API, even the old examples still work as is with Java 3D 1.6.0 :)

Comment: Never mind. With projects as big as java3d there is always the problem to decide if a particular piece of code just happened to be like it is, or if there's more behind a seemingly quirk coding. It saves a lot of time if one has at least some raw understanding of what the programmers had in mind.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64426/discussion-between-gyro-gearloose-and-gouessej).